# Spark: Using iterator lambda function in RDD map()

Tags: python, mapreduce, functional-programming, apache-spark

I have simple dataset on HDFS that I'm loading into Spark. It looks like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
...
```

basically, a matrix. I'm trying to implement something that requires grouping matrix rows, and so I'm trying to add a unique key for every row like so:

```
(1, [1 1 1 1 1 ... ])
(2, [1 1 1 1 1 ... ])
(3, [1 1 1 1 1 ... ])
...
```

I tried something somewhat naive: set a global variable and write a lambda function to iterate over the global variable:

```
# initialize global index
global global_index
global_index = 0

# function to generate keys
def generateKeys(x):
    global_index+=1
    return (global_index,x)

# read in data and operate on it
data = sc.textFile("/data.txt")

...some preprocessing...

data.map(generateKeys)
```

And it seemed to not recognize the existence of the global variable.

Is there an easy way that comes to mind to do this?

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: Never mind, the global variable solution seems to work fine. However, I would be interested in seeing a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: The global variable solution is incorrect unless you only use a single Spark worker because each worker will have its own copy of `global_index` and you will wind up assigning duplicate keys.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939153/how-to-assign-unique-contiguous-numbers-to-elements-in-a-spark-rdd

Comment: Thanks Josh. I was testing locally so that error didn't pop up, but you are correct. The best solution actually is to generate two seperate RDDs, one for the index, and the other for your data. Then zip them together using the `zip` function (new since Spark 0.9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> lsts = [
...     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
...     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
...     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
...     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
...     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
...     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
...     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
...     [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
...     ]
...
>>> list(enumerate(lsts))
[(0, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (1, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (2, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (3, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (4, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (5, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (6, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]),
 (7, [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2])]
```

`enumerate` generates unique index for each item in the iterable and yields tuples with values `(index, original_item)`

If you want to start numbering with other than `0`, pass the starting value to `enumerate` as second parameter.

```
>>> list(enumerate(lsts, 1))
[(1, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (2, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (3, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (4, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (5, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (6, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]),
 (7, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]),
 (8, [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2])]
```

Note, that the `list` is used to get real values out from `enumerate` which is iterator and not a function, returning lists.

## Alternative: globally available id assigner

`enumerate` is easy to use, but if you would need to assing id in diferrent pieces of your code, it
would become difficult or impossible. For such a case, globally available generator (as drafter in
OP) would be the way to go.

`itertools` provide `count` which can serve our need:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> idgen = count()
```

Now we have (globally available) `idgen` generator ready to yield unique ids.

We can test it by a function `prid` (print id):

```
>>> def prid():
...     id = idgen.next()
...     print id
...
>>> prid()
0
>>> prid()
1
>>> prid()
2
>>> prid()
3
```

As it works we can test it on list of values:

```
>>> lst = ['100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109']
```

and define actual function, which when called with a value would return tuple `(id, value)`

```
>>> def assignId(val):
...     return (idgen.next(), val)
...
```

note, that there is no need to declare `idgen` as global as we are not going to change it's value (the `idgen` will only change it's internal status when called, but will still remain the same generator).

Test, if it works:

```
>>> assignId("ahahah")
(4, 'ahahah')
```

and try it on the list:

```
>>> map(assignId, lst)
[(5, '100'),
 (6, '101'),
 (7, '102'),
 (8, '103'),
 (9, '104'),
 (10, '105'),
 (11, '106'),
 (12, '107'),
 (13, '108'),
 (14, '109')]
```

The main diferrence to `enumerate` solution is, we can assign ids one by one anywhere in the code
without doing it all from within one all processing `enumerate`.

```
>>> assignId("lonely line")
(15, 'lonely line')
```

Comment: This requires `collect()`-ing the RDD back to the driver, no? For small datasets this will work, but I don't think this will scale since `enumerate()` as used here is not parallelizable.

Comment: @NickChammas `enumerate` does not require collecting all the results. Try `from itertools import
count` then `itr = enumerate(count())` and finally repeat calling `itr.next()`. It returns results
one by one while the `count()` iterable is able providing almost infinite number of numbers.
Regarding parallelization - the question is using `map` so I have expected similar scenario. You are right that for parallel processing we would need some global id generator.

Comment: @JackChua I have added alternative `assignId` solution to my answer.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky - "`enumerate` does not require collecting all the results." Yes, it does. `collect()` is an operation on RDDs, an abstraction that Apache Spark provides. It gathers all of the contents of the RDD back to the driver as a list. `enumerate()` is a Python builtin function, and you cannot call it directly on RDDs. So if someone has an RDD with 300GB of data in it distributed across several machines -- as would be normal with Spark; that's what it's for -- they cannot use `enumerate()` as you describe without pushing all that data back to the driver node. That won't work.

Comment: Here's a quick example in PySpark to illustrate:

>>> a = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> enumerate(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'RDD' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

try `dataRdd.zipWithIndex` and eventually swap the resulting tuple if having the index first is a must.