# FlatMap Values and Their Column Index

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say I have a data set that is

```
0,11,2,3,4,5,56,7
0,1,21,13,45,5,61,75
01,1,2,3,54,55,6,75
```

What I am looking to do is flatmap the values to a key being the column index and the value being the value. Can anyone give me guidance? I'm finding it hard to get the column index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating key value pairs, where the key is the list-index and the value is the value at that index could look like this:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: enumerate(x))
```

This is of course assuming that your data is already an RDD.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that your RDD is of a sequence type, you could do:

```
rdd.flatMap(line => line.zipWithIndex.map(tuple => tuple.swap))
```

Comment: Its just plain text. I found this, it looks to be the equivalent in python: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/04/how-to-use-pythons-enumerate-and-zip-to/ and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689363/spark-using-iterator-lambda-function-in-rdd-map I think playing aorund with these two things might make it possible? Ultimately my goal is to do column level operations based on a key being the column.

Comment: Any help with the python version for it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you want to do column-level operations you might want to consider using DataFrames (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame)