# Additing a new column to DataFrame in Spark

Tags: scala, exception, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I want to add a new column with row id to a `DataFrame` in `Spark(Scala)`. This is the approach i took. I am creating a new row with index id and a new `StructType` with another `StructField` included.

```
 val rdd = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(indexedRow => Row.fromSeq(indexedRow._2.toString ++ indexedRow._1.toSeq ))
 val list = StructType(Seq(StructField("Row Number", StringType, true)).++(df.schema.fields))
 sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, list).show() // fails
```

I am getting the following exception when i run.

```
scala.MatchError: 0 (of class java.lang.Character)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2.apply(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:401)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$6.apply(SQLContext.scala:492)
```

But the structtype and rdd have the expected output.
Can anyone help me with this? Please

I have tried with Spark2.10 1.6.0 and 1.6.1 versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just one small mistake, and that's in prepending the string value to the sequence of fields - instead of:

```
indexedRow._2.toString ++ indexedRow._1.toSeq
```

You should use:

```
indexedRow._2.toString +: indexedRow._1.toSeq
```

The first implementation actually converts the string into a `Seq[Char]` and then *concatenates* the two sequences, so you end up with something like `Seq('1', '2', "f1Val", "f2Val")` instead of `Seq("12", "f1Val", "f2Val")`. The exception you see is Spark trying to parse the first `Char` as a `StringType` and failing.

Comment: Thank you. I helped. Well explained answer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24718198/1184310) answer for a better way of assigning unique IDs for rdd rows(RDD.zipWithUniqueId)

Comment: I want to add sequential id to each row. However, the information is very helpful.