# How to achieve Rownum feature in Spark Dataframe similar to oracle rownum

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark and I am trying to create a rownumer for large dataset.
I tried using row_number window function, which works fine but its not performance efficient as I am not using partitionBy clause.

Eg:

```
 val df= Seq(
        ("041", false),
        ("042", false),
        ("043", false)
      ).toDF("id", "flag")
```

Result should be :

```
val df= Seq(
        ("041", false,1),
        ("042", false,2),
        ("043", false,3)
      ).toDF("id", "flag","rownum")
```

currently I am using

```
df.withColumn("rownum",row_number().over(Window.orderBy($"id")))
```

**Is there any other way to achieve this result without using window functions?
I also tried monotonicallyIncresingID and ZipwithIndex**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `monotonicallyIncreasingId` to get a rowNum feature

`val df2 = df.withColumn("rownum",monotonicallyIncreasingId)`

here the index would start with 0.

to start index with 1, one add +1 to the `monotonicallyIncreasingId`

`val df2 = df.withColumn("rownum",monotonicallyIncreasingId+1)`

```
scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("rownum",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, flag: boolean, rownum: bigint]

scala> df2.show
+---+-----+------+
| id| flag|rownum|
+---+-----+------+
|041|false|     0|
|042|false|     1|
|043|false|     2|
+---+-----+------+


scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("rownum",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, flag: boolean, rownum: bigint]

scala> df2.show
+---+-----+------+
| id| flag|rownum|
+---+-----+------+
|041|false|     0|
|042|false|     1|
|043|false|     2|
+---+-----+------+


scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("rownum",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, flag: boolean, rownum: bigint]

scala> df2.show
+---+-----+------+
| id| flag|rownum|
+---+-----+------+
|041|false|     0|
|042|false|     1|
|043|false|     2|
+---+-----+------+


scala> var df2 = df.withColumn("rownum",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, flag: boolean, rownum: bigint]

scala> df2.show
+---+-----+------+
| id| flag|rownum|
+---+-----+------+
|041|false|     0|
|042|false|     1|
|043|false|     2|
+---+-----+------+


scala> df2 = df.withColumn("rownum",monotonicallyIncreasingId)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, flag: boolean, rownum: bigint]

scala> df2.show
+---+-----+------+
| id| flag|rownum|
+---+-----+------+
|041|false|     0|
|042|false|     1|
|043|false|     2|
+---+-----+------+
```

Comment: "monotonicallyIncreasingId" generates random numbers if we run multiple times, there is no surity of occurrence that generation will be from 0 or 1.

Comment: other way is to convert the dataframe to `RDD` and use zipWithIndex function. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939153/how-to-assign-unique-contiguous-numbers-to-elements-in-a-spark-rdd

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3098 : read this,
This is also not serving the purpose.. Thanks!!