# What is the difference between zipWithUniqueId and zipWithIndex in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The documentation says that one triggers a spark job and the other one does not. I am not sure I understand what that means. Could you help me understand the difference between the two?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24718198/1386551

Answer (score 0):

The source of truth comes from latest code:

```
  /**
   * Zips this RDD with its element indices. The ordering is first based on the partition index
   * and then the ordering of items within each partition. So the first item in the first
   * partition gets index 0, and the last item in the last partition receives the largest index.
   *
   * This is similar to Scala's zipWithIndex but it uses Long instead of Int as the index type.
   * This method needs to trigger a spark job when this RDD contains more than one partitions.
   *
   * @note Some RDDs, such as those returned by groupBy(), do not guarantee order of
   * elements in a partition. The index assigned to each element is therefore not guaranteed,
   * and may even change if the RDD is reevaluated. If a fixed ordering is required to guarantee
   * the same index assignments, you should sort the RDD with sortByKey() or save it to a file.
   */
  def zipWithIndex(): RDD[(T, Long)] = withScope {
    new ZippedWithIndexRDD(this)
  }

  /**
   * Zips this RDD with generated unique Long ids. Items in the kth partition will get ids k, n+k,
   * 2*n+k, ..., where n is the number of partitions. So there may exist gaps, but this method
   * won't trigger a spark job, which is different from [[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD#zipWithIndex]].
   *
   * @note Some RDDs, such as those returned by groupBy(), do not guarantee order of
   * elements in a partition. The unique ID assigned to each element is therefore not guaranteed,
   * and may even change if the RDD is reevaluated. If a fixed ordering is required to guarantee
   * the same index assignments, you should sort the RDD with sortByKey() or save it to a file.
   */
  def zipWithUniqueId(): RDD[(T, Long)]
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1396